# Data defined override: What does "double coord [X,Y] as <= 0.0 =>" look like?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to dynamically change the placement offset of a label's background polygon. The hover text from that menu entry tells me:

> Expected input: double coord [X,Y] as <= 0.0 =>

I have no clue what is meant by that and i am tired of messing around so could please someone replace appropriately the ? in the following expression:

```
CASE WHEN "HELP" > 9000 THEN ???? END
```

I am also about to deal with negative decimal numbers here.

Comment: Perhaps these posts might help: [Data Defined Override XY offset input](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219360/data-defined-override-xy-offset-input); and [Data defined labeling of coordinates](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220721/data-defined-labeling-of-coordinates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

```
case when  "arrow"  < 0 then '-5,0'
when  "arrow"  > 0 then '5,0' end
```